# CSS Absolute positioning not working

Tags: asp.net, css, widget, css-position

[image]

Hi,

Attached screenchot is mockup of our application where in their are -n- number of widgets which are freely movable all through the screen. Everything else works fine except minimize widget functionality. PFA screen shot for the actual problem which comes up after clicking settings button (start of arrow in screen shot). The problem that we are facing is with the positioning of minimize block. We need to achieve it just below the setting button, but it is coming out of widget area.

**Please find below code snippet and detail for the same.**

The Minimize functionality is being formatted using the JQUERY file with forming the HTML using UL-LI

The CSS for the UL is done using below code snippet.

```
ul. editModule
{
Display:none;
z-index:200;
position:absolute;
left:177px;
top:3px;
padding-top:2px;
clear:left;
}

The minimize box in the screen shot is being made using below code snippet:-

<ul class=”editModule”><li class=”editColor”><ul class=”moduleColor”><li class=”module-colorWheel”></li><li class=”moduleChoice-blue” title=”module-blue”></li><li class=”moduleChoice-green” title=”module-green” ></li><li class=”moduleChoice-red” title=”module-red” ></li><li class=”moduleChoice-yellow” title=”module-yellow” ></li></ul></li>
<li class=”applyAll”><a href=”#” class=”closeModule”>Close Widget</a></li>
<li class=”minimize”><a href=”#” class=”minimizeModule”>Minimize Widget</a></li>
</ul></li></ul>
```

When I click on the settings button(start of arrow) it opens the minimize functional box for the widget in a wrong location. Ideally the position should be just below the Settings icon in the hearder i.e. Top right corner.

Any sort of help regarding this will be great. if any further input is required do post comments.

Comment: What does PFA mean? Edit: Probably 'Please Find Attached'.

Comment: Where is your widget placed in the page? Could you provide some more code?

Comment: @Ariel : Yeah it is please Find Attached

Comment: mu is too short: Yeah they are valid. Html created in string.

Comment: @Stefy: It is a user control and we have used JQuery draggable to make it float around. Sorry I can't provide much of code.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that the pop-out div is showing up in the wrong location?
Please try to give the *parent* container of the pop-out element a CSS style of *position:relative*.
position:absolute works on the whole screen, unless the parent container of the absolute positioned element also has positioning set.

Erik

EDIT: I have made you some HTMl where the editModule is placed absolute relative to the titlebar:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

```
<style>

ul li {text-decoration:none; float:left;}

.titlebar {
    background-color:green;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    }

.editModule
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 20px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:right;
    padding-top:2px;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="titlebar">

    <ul class="editModule">
        <li class="editColor">
            <ul class="moduleColor">
                <li class="module-colorWheel">CW</li>
                <li class="moduleChoice-blue" title="module-blue">BLUE</li>
                <li class="moduleChoice-green" title="module-green" >GREEN</li>
                <li class="moduleChoice-red" title="module-red" >RED</li>
                <li class="moduleChoice-yellow" title="module-yellow" >YEL</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="applyAll"><a href="#" class="closeModule">Close Widget</a></li>
        <li class="minimize"><a href="#" class="minimizeModule">Minimize Widget</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

<!-- </li></ul> -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, as you would like the popup box to be positioned at the top right of the parent container, I would advise positioning the popup box using top and right rather than top and left as you have in your code.

Comment: @rico : As per your solution of using the Parent container when we give positioin:relative the parent CSS is not being catched. Only the child CSS is being chached. What do we have to do in this case.

Comment: @Chat: I'm not sure what you mean; 
Does it work, but are the styles of the parent container skipped?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `clear: left;` command. Clear together with `position: absolute` doesn't really make sense.